# Data in database column not showing but exists

Tags: mysql

I have this problem that occurred today I am left baffled, The issues is that when I insert data in one of my database table called tbl_template_log, it exists but it is not showing in browse mode I am using phpMyAdmin.

But when I click "edit" the data appears correct...

Hopefully my question is understandable if not ask me for additional details.

This is how my data appear in browse Mode:

[image]

And The proof that the data in user_id actually exists after running this query "`SELECT * FROM tbl_template_log`" is here:

[image]

tbl_template_log structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_template_log` (
  `templog_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `savetemp_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `send_to` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `email_send` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`templog_id`),
  KEY `tbl_user.user_id` (`user_id`,`temp_id`,`savetemp_id`),
  KEY `tbl_template.temp_id` (`temp_id`),
  KEY `tbl_saved_template.savetemp_id` (`savetemp_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=85 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_template_log`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_template_log` (`templog_id`, `user_id`, `temp_id`, `savetemp_id`, `send_date`, `send_to`, `email_send`) VALUES
(83, 77, NULL, NULL, '2014-05-20 22:08:25', 'tomasz@onetwotrade.com', '<html blahh blahh>'),

--
-- Constraints for table `tbl_template_log`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_template_log`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_template_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_template_log_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`temp_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_template` (`temp_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_template_log_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`savetemp_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_saved_template` (`savedtemp_id`);
```

Comment: do `SELECT * FROM tbl_template_log` and check if its there.

Comment: Hi thx for your suggestion, yes I did that and the data is showing, but why it does not show in browse mode...?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a different page?

Comment: Nope...When I login into my phpMyAdmin select my database and go into tbl_template_log the data in user_id is not showing but it exists, I checked this by clicking edit and running the above query, I don't understand why it is like this

Comment: What “above query”? `SELECT * FROM tbl_template_log`? That is an unordered query, try a `ORDER BY` clause. If you cannot post an image to SO, post it to another service like PasteBin and post the URL.

Comment: Please check my Links to screen dumps

Comment: please post a screenshot or an sql export of your table structur. Is the ID defined as a (foreign) key?

Comment: Please do have look at my table structure

Comment: I think it has something to do with your foreign keys in innoDB... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem, firstly thank you all who tried to help me, Funny enough the problem was with my Safari browser :o, I cleared my browsing History, Catche & Cookies then everything started to work suddenly

Answer (score 0):

Scroll all the way down in PHP my admin and change the `Show 30 row(s)` value to something like 100 or 500 or how many you want.

Your value is most probably on a different page.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I have totally empty the table and left only 3 rows, and in all three rows the user_id is not visible but exists.

Comment: That is very strange indeed.. Let me mull on this for a while

Comment: Yep I never seen something like this, it happened over the sudden

Comment: Please check my Links to screen dumps